# Ruby Monkey Patched Logger does not work in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some helper methods on my ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger such as displaying KeyValue pairs, it all works fine from **rails s** but fails in **rails c**

In rails s, I can see that my Logger extends BufferedLogger and that is the class I have chosen to MonkeyPatch, I have also tested this out with ActiveSupport::Logger as well.

I had thought that rails c ran through the same initializers that rails s used, am I wrong in thinking that?

Do I need to run some sort of initializer when starting rails c?

Location of my file is:

- config/initializers/active_support_logger.rb

Error is here:

[image]

Sample Snippet listed here

```
class ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger

    def kv(key, value)
        info('%-50s %s' % ["#{key}: ".brown, value])
    end

    def line
        info(@@l.brown)
    end

    def block(message)
        line
        info(message)
        line
    end

end
```

Comment: How have you configured the logger?

Comment: Your stack trace shows that the class being used is `Logger`, not `BufferedLogger`.

Comment: When I use rails s, I can see that my logger extends BufferedLogger so it is fine to hook into that class for the application. As to how have I configured it, I'm not really sure because I'm new to Ruby and using an existing system that works fine. I had thought that anything I can do in the rails server would also work fine in the rails console, I thought rails console loaded up the same way? Am I wrong, do I need to specify all the configurations somewhere when using rails c

Comment: I think it would help if you also show output of `Logger.ancestors`. Where do you put the patching script?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend subclassing `ActiveSupport::Logger` (or `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` if you really want though it's deprecated in Rails 4) instead of monkey-patching. Rails provides a configuration option to override the logger instance used by the app. This works in any context that loads the Rails environment, including the server and console.

There are a number of ways you can do this; a quick and dirty way to get you started is to just define the class and set the logger instance in an initializer that will get loaded during the initialization process of the Rails environment:

```
# config/initializers/my_logger.rb

class MyLogger < ::ActiveSupport::Logger 
  # additional methods and overrides
end

Rails.logger = MyLogger.new(Rails.root.join("log", "#{Rails.env}.log"))
```

For more info, check out the Rails guide to debugging applications: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look at doing it that way, that seems nicer that monkey patching

Comment: Just wondering still how I get this to work with Rails Console, when I do Rails.logger = MyLogger.new(Rails.root.join("log", "#{Rails.env}.log")) it fails to find my code in the models, there reason is that the ActionController::Base.logger & ActiveRecord::Base.logger are NOT setup correctly and never will be because that is only done by Rails Server. I have tried manually assining those loggers, but in rails console, but it does not seem to log correctly anyway

Comment: Where are you setting `Rails.logger = MyLogger.new`?

Comment: Just in Rails Console IRB

Comment: Set the logger in `config/initializers/my_logger.rb`. Any file in the initializers directory will be loaded during the environment boot process, i.e. when `rails s` or `rails c` starts up.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, that statement above is not correct. The initializers load fine in rails s, but NOT in rails c. I'm currently using a monkey patched approach to the extending the logger and it is not working for rails c, have also used a class extending technique and it too does not work in rails c

Comment: Try this: `echo "raise 'initializer loaded'" >> config/initializers/raise_exception.rb && bundle exec rails c`. Does this raise an error with the message 'initializer loaded'?